# Parsing jsdoc style comments with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

What would the regexp be to pull out the value of `title` in the following string:

```
/*
  @title: Untitled 
  @description: This is an example
*/
```

Comment: That's a comment, are you sure you even have access to it ?

Comment: `/\@title\:(*.?)\@/`

Comment: Yes. I'm running it against a flat file stored inside a blob.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should do the job:

```
var r = /\s*\@title\:(.*)$/gmi;
var title = r.exec(yourString)[1].trim();
```

Comment: This will also capture leading space, so you may want to add a line to remove any leading space from the captured title.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will capture the following line for the empty title case :)  I think you're better off dealing with the leading space after you apply the regex.

Comment: Reverted to previous version. I added a trim() to fix the problem :)